# Is there a standard abstraction for this request-response type?

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations, arrows, haskell-pipes

I have the following type:

```
data S req rsp = Done rsp | Next req (rsp -> S req rsp)
```

The idea is to use it as a pure representation for network communication, i.e:

```
... Next GetUser $ \uid -> Next (Login uid) $ \success -> Done success
```

Which would then be evaluated by some impure function `eval`.

Now, what is this (if anything?) It's not a monad, neither an arrow, as far as I can see. It seems to be something between a stream/pipe/automaton/fsm and the continuation monad. This makes me think that there might be a better representation for this type of thing, but what?

Comment: This can be viewed as a free monad if it is rewritten `data S req rsp r = Done r | Next req (rsp -> S req rsp r)` Then it's effectively the free monad on the functor `Compose ((,) req) ((->) resp)` or `data Request req resp r = Request req (resp -> r`. It is very common to use a constructor of this type in writing a functor for a free monad, as you can see from some of the examples in http://degoes.net/articles/modern-fp Note that all four constructors of his `HttpF` functor, `GET`, `POST` etc,  are effectively of this shape.

Comment: In `pipes`, the `Server` (or equivalently `Client`) type is a (monad transformer) version of it. Then we can write say ` let mkRequest :: Monad m => req -> Client req resp m resp; mkRequest = request` (Here an underlying monad is presupposed, as if you had applied `FreeT` rather than `Free` to the request functor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [Free Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free). 
The idea is that you have a description of instructions for which you can have multiple interpreters like your `eval` function. Free Monad abstracts over the pattern that this task has. For details I recommend [this great post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html).

To adapt your type to `Free` we can do the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data Instruction req rsp next =
  Respond rsp |
  Interact req (rsp -> next)
  deriving (Functor)

type S req rsp =
  Free (Instruction req rsp)

respond :: rsp -> S req rsp ()
respond rsp =
  liftF (Respond rsp)

interact :: req -> S req rsp rsp
interact req =
  liftF (Interact req id)
```

Now, thanks to `Free`, `S req rsp` is a monad, which means that you can now compose your `respond` and `interact` functions using `Monad` API.

There's more to it. The `respond` and `interact` functions could be generated using Template Haskell with the following extra code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Monad.Free.TH

makeFree ''Instruction
```

Comment: Yep, now that you say it it's obvious. I was hoping it would be something with a little more structure though :)

Answer (score 5):

Your type looks a little bit like [Apfelmus's `operational` monad](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/operational-monad.html), also known as [the `Freer` monad](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf):

```
data Program inst a where
    Return :: a -> Program inst a
    Bind :: inst a -> (a -> Program inst b) -> Program inst b

instance Monad (Program inst) where
    return = Return
    Return x >>= f = f x
    Bind i next >>= f = Bind i (fmap (>>= f) next)

-- plus the usual Functor and Applicative boilerplate
```

`Program :: (* -> *) -> * -> *` represents a sequence of *instructions* `inst`, which use their type parameter to indicate the "return type" of running that instruction in an interpreter. The `Bind` constructor takes an instruction and a continuation which can be run after the result of the instruction has been received from the interpreter. Note how `a` is existentially quantified, reflecting the fact that the types of all the intermediate steps in a computation are not relevant to the overall type.

The important difference between `Program` and your type is that the type of the response is determined by the instruction, rather than being fixed over the whole computation. This allows us to make more fine-grained guarantees about the response that each request expects to provoke.

For example, here's the state monad written as a `Program`:

```
data StateI s r where
    Get :: StateI s s
    Put :: s -> StateI s ()

type State s = Program (StateI s)

get :: State s s
get = Bind Get Return
put :: s -> State s ()
put s = Bind (Put s) Return

modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
modify f = do
    x <- get
    put (f x)

runState :: State s a -> s -> (s, a)
runState (Return x) s = (s, x)
runState (Bind Get next) s = runState (next s) s
runState (Bind (Put s) next) _ = runState (next ()) s
```

The co-Yoneda lemma tells us that `Program` is isomorphic to `Free`. Intuitively, it's a free monad based on `->`'s `Functor` instance. For certain operations like left-associative binds, `Program` can be more efficient than `Free`, because its `>>=` is based on function composition, rather than possibly-expensively `fmap`ping an arbitrary `Functor`.